# How can I check for SYN packets using multithreading?

Tags: python, multithreading, tcp, port

I am developing a Python program that detects a port scan. In order to do that I need to listen all the ports and check for received SYN packets and I want to use multithreading to check for as many ports as possible simultaneously. What is the best way to implement it? Below is the code that I used to see if it was working for a single port or not.

```
import socket

# AF_INET for IPv4 and SOCK_RAW specifies raw packets and IPPROTO_TCP for TCO protocol
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)

# for returning immediately even though there is no data
sock.setblocking(False)

try:
    # test for TCP port
    sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', 80))
except socket.error:
    print("Socket Error")

# checks packets constantly
print("Looking for packets...")
while True:
    try:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    except socket.error:
        pass
    else:
        # syn flag is the second bit of 13th byte
        if data[13] & 0x02:
            print("Syn Packet Detected")
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you having problems with the code you've written or are you hoping that someone will write it for you. If the former, please show your troublesome code. If the latter, you're in the wrong place

Comment: @DarkKnight my apologies, I added the test code now. I am looking for both guidance and code samples at this point

Comment: Trying to create a listener on all ports for SYN is probably not the best approach in the first place. Better to use either raw sockets or redirect all ports to a single socket using firewall rules. And even if you want to bind+listen on all ports a single-threaded event-based approach might actually be simpler. And note that the way you use raw sockets is very strange, no need to bind it to a port

Comment: It will be much easier to use iptables/netfilter to send just the syn packets to to user space.  There are python bindings for libnetfilter_queue, but I have no personal experience with them.